# querySelector doesn't work but getElementBy does

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get a button in my javascript but for some reason `querySelector` doesn't work, but both `getElementById` and `getElementsByClassName` does, also if i use `querySelector` on browser console returns the button

main.html:

```
<button id="adicionar-paciente" class="botao bto-principal">Adicionar</button>
  </form>
    </section>
    <script src="js/principal.js"></script>
    <script src="js/add.js" defer></script>
</body>
```

add.js:

```
(() => {
    let button = document.querySelector("#adicionar-paciente");
    button.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
    })
})()
```

The script is already at the end o the body with the atribut defer and i already tried use `window.onload`, `document.observe("dom:loaded", () => {`, `Event.observe(window, 'load', () => {`

Comment: Note: There's no point of the `defer` attribute if the script is located at the bottom of the `body`

Comment: There's absolutely no difference between the requirements for `document.querySelector()` and `document.getElementById()`. This doesn't seem possible.

Comment: Unless you are using a *very* old browser (MSIE 7 or earlier / Firefox 3 or earlier) both `document.getElementById()` and `document.querySelector()` should be supported; are you sure there isn't any typo or case sensitivity issue in your original code?

Comment: Have you also tried using `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => { /* your button code here */ })` ?

Comment: @nmina I think, if the problem were related to the DOM not completely loading, both `querySelector()` and `getElementById()` should fail; the fact that only the first one seems not to work, suggests the cause of the issue is probably somewhere else.

Comment: @Spectric It was just pure despair

Comment: @secan I'm using up to date Edge, and no case sensitivity issue

Comment: @nmina Yes, i did tried